# Yelp ruby gem on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, yelp

I have this code as an initializer in yelp.rb:

```
Yelp.client.configure do |config|
 config.consumer_key = ENV['config.consumer_key']
 config.consumer_secret = ENV['config.consumer_secret']
 config.token = ENV['config.token']
 config.token_secret = ENV['config.token_secret']
end
```

I have a yelp.yml file that loads all this in and it works great in development.

As soon as I push it to heroku (I have all my keys set in Heroku as well and have triple verified no spelling errors) I get this error 'Yelp::Error::MissingAPIKeys: You're missing an API key'

I've ran code in Rails C on development (see below) and it passes, ran the exact same code in Rails c on the Heroku side and I get that error. I even tried it without using ENV and used the exact api keys and same error.

```
client = Yelp::Client.new({  
  consumer_key = ENV['config.consumer_key'],
  consumer_secret = ENV['config.consumer_secret'],
  token = ENV['config.token'],
  token_secret = ENV['config.token_secret'] })
```

What is different between Production and Development?

UPDATE: 
Got it working...
I was able to get it working this way...

```
def index
      current_user.zip_code.present? ? @zip = current_user.zip_code :     @zip = "94101"
      parameters = { term: 'auto repair', limit: 9 }
      @search = client.search(@zip, parameters)
  end

  private
  def client
     @client ||= Yelp::Client.new({ consumer_key: ENV['config.consumer_key'],
      consumer_secret: ENV['config.consumer_secret'],
      token: ENV['config.token'],
      token_secret: ENV['config.token_secret']
    })
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `heroku config --app app-name` to check if config variables are being set correctly, if that looks correct. Then try running rails console on Heroku using `heroku run rails console --app app-name` to check if the `Yelp::Client` is loading the `env` properly.

If you just follow the `ENV` naming convention as provided in the [gem readme](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby) you might avoid this issue altogether.

```
Yelp.client.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.token = YOUR_TOKEN
  config.token_secret = YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

Comment: great. could also tell what the issue was, will be interested to understand the problem better. Or better yet add it as an answer to this question.